# Programmatically switch to production sources for webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website project that includes several JavaScript files at the end of the body of `index.html`, some from 3rd party libraries, the rest that I wrote:

```
<html>
  ...
  <body>
  ...
  <script src="lib/lib1.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/lib2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/js1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/js2.js"></script>
  ...
  </body>
</html>
```

For production, I naturally want an optimized set of includes. For one, as part of a larger build process (using Maven) all of the non-library JavaScript is combined, optimized and minified. I would also like to use minified library files (perhaps from a CDN):

```
<html>
  ...
  <body>
  ...
  <script src="lib/lib1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn/lib2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/combined.min.js"></script>
  ...
  </body>
</html>
```

A similar process is used for our CSS.

So, my question is: **What techniques do people use to accomplish such a switch between sets of scripts/CSS?**

Since my production build process already uses Maven, I'm open to suggestions involving a Maven plugin such as [this one](http://code.google.com/p/maven-replacer-plugin/). However, for workflow reasons, I would like to keep `index.html` clean (e.g., I don't want a token in place of the script includes, it needs to work without further processing.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a good Maven-based solution, using the [maven-replacer-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-replacer-plugin/). In my HTML files, I block my development and production code using comments:

```
<!-- DEVELOPMENT -->
<script src="lib/lib1.js"></script>
<script src="lib/lib2.js"></script>
<script src="js/js1.js"></script>
<script src="js/js2.js"></script>
<!-- /DEVELOPMENT -->
<!-- PRODUCTION
<script src="lib/lib1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn/lib2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/combined.min.js"></script>
/PRODUCTION -->
```

Then, I use the following configuration block for the Maven plugin:

```
<configuration>
    <file>index.html</file>
    <replacements>
        <replacement>
            <token>&lt;!-- DEVELOPMENT --&gt;</token>
            <value>&lt;!-- DEVELOPMENT</value>
        </replacement>
        <replacement>
            <token>&lt;!-- /DEVELOPMENT --&gt;</token>
            <value>/DEVELOPMENT --&gt;</value>
        </replacement>
        <replacement>
            <token>&lt;!-- PRODUCTION</token>
            <value>&lt;!-- PRODUCTION --&gt;</value>
        </replacement>
        <replacement>
            <token>/PRODUCTION --&gt;</token>
            <value>&lt;!-- /PRODUCTION --&gt;</value>
        </replacement>
    </replacements>
</configuration>
```

After running, the development code is toggled off and the production code is toggled on:

```
<!-- DEVELOPMENT
<script src="lib/lib1.js"></script>
<script src="lib/lib2.js"></script>
<script src="js/js1.js"></script>
<script src="js/js2.js"></script>
/DEVELOPMENT -->
<!-- PRODUCTION -->
<script src="lib/lib1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn/lib2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/combined.min.js"></script>
<!-- /PRODUCTION -->
```

Obviously, you could easily remove the development code instead.